# Android 10 notification color doesn't change when dark theme changes

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-10.0, android-dark-theme, android-darkmode

I have a notification with some actions. And I use the [Notification.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder) to set a color for the action and icon tinting. Here is the full code to create the notification.

```kotlin
val notification = Notification.Builder(context,
                CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(mainText)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.small_icon)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .addAction(Notification.Action.Builder(
                        Icon.createWithResource(
                                this, R.drawable.action_icon),
                        getString(R.string.action_title),
                        actionPendingIntent)
                        .build())
                .setStyle(Notification.InboxStyle()
                        .addLine(mainText)
                        .addLine(subText)
                        .addLine(secondSubText)
                        .setBigContentTitle(title)
                        .setSummaryText(summaryText))
                .setColor(getColor(R.color.notification_accent))
                .build()
```

The color `R.color.notification_accent` is declared both in `values` and in `values-night`, and has different colors. Also the base theme of the application extends from `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight`. And the whole application changes correctly between the themes when dark theme is enabled/disabled in the device.

When I create the notification it is always created correctly, so when dark theme is on, the color from `values-night` is used, and when it's off the `values` color is used.

The problem is when the theme changes and the notification is already visible. I can see the notification is actually changing since the background changes from dark to light, but the color of the action is not changing.

I'm guessing this happens because the color is not part of the notification theme, but I'm not sure how that can be handled, or if it's a bug in the [Notification.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder).

Edit:
This behaviour happens on an emulator running API 29. When running the app on a device the behaviour is correct, the colors change. I'm answering the question myself saying to use a device.

Comment: Why are you setting a different color based on light/dark? Note that notifications already tint your color to make it readable on the background color.

Comment: Well my notification had the action buttons dark gray when dark theme was on, so it was barely readable. And changing the app colors based on light / dark is the recommended approach. So why not also change the notification?

Comment: The color you set on a notification should be your app's primary branding color. Is your app's primary branding color dark gray?

Comment: No, without the line of set color the notification action color is dark gray. No idea why. But some other apps out there have the same. So I guess it's the system default, but I don't know if there is a color in the app theme that can override it. The color I'm using now is my primary accent color. But it shouldn't matter which color I use. In any case, it only happens in the emulator, so it's fine I guess.

Comment: I just want to point out that Android notifications colours don't point to your app's colour resources. When you call `setColor()` on the notification, you are passing in the ARGB colour value, not the colour resource id. So any resource qualifiers you use, such as `values-night` won't automatically update the notification as they change.

Comment: What I've found, on both emulators and real devices, is that the notification small icon colour can change between day and night mode, but this is because the system changes the colour in cases where the original colour (set when the notification was created) does not have enough contrast in the changed day/night mode.  The change in colour is not because of different values being set in `values` and `values-night`.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

This issue happens on an emulator. In a real device the issue doesn't happen and the colors of the notification change when dark theme changes.